# $SU(2)$ breakdown to $U(1)$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, higgs, symmetry-breaking

When we break a lagrangian symmetric with $SU(2)$ with a higgs bosons being the adjoint representation, using the following v.e.v for higgs $\phi$,

$$\langle \phi \rangle = (0,0, \rho)^T.$$

Two photons aquire masses, and one remains massless. My doubt is about the new symmetry patterning. Can i say that it break down to

$$SU(2) \rightarrow U(1) \times U(1)$$

Since $A_{1,2}$ still is invariant under a phase? or the breakdown is just

$$SU(2) \rightarrow U(1)$$

Comment: The latter option, since you broke two generators and had two Goldstone bosons which got Higgsed. The surviving U(1) connects them to each other. Show your work!

Answer (score 2):

A general $SU(2)$ matrix in the $j=1$ representation is given by
\begin{align}
U &= \exp \left[ i \Theta ( \sin\theta \cos \varphi J_x + \sin\theta \sin \varphi J_y + \cos \theta J_z ) \right] \\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
 \sin ^2\theta \left(\cos \Theta \sin ^2\varphi+\cos ^2\varphi\right)+\cos ^2\theta \cos \Theta & \sin ^2\theta \sin ^2\left(\frac{\Theta }{2}\right) \sin (2 \varphi )+\cos \theta \sin
   \Theta & \sin (2 \theta ) \sin ^2\left(\frac{\Theta }{2}\right) \cos \varphi-\sin \theta \sin \Theta \sin \varphi \\
 \sin ^2\theta \sin ^2\left(\frac{\Theta }{2}\right) \sin (2 \varphi )-\cos \theta \sin \Theta & \sin ^2\theta \left(\cos \Theta \cos ^2\varphi+\sin ^2\varphi\right)+\cos ^2\theta \cos
   \Theta & \sin (2 \theta ) \sin ^2\left(\frac{\Theta }{2}\right) \sin \varphi+\sin \theta \sin \Theta \cos \varphi \\
 \sin \theta \sin \Theta \sin \varphi+\sin (2 \theta ) \sin ^2\left(\frac{\Theta }{2}\right) \cos \varphi & \sin (2 \theta ) \sin ^2\left(\frac{\Theta }{2}\right) \sin \varphi-\sin \theta \sin
   \Theta \cos \varphi & \sin ^2\theta \cos \Theta+\cos ^2\theta 
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{align}
PS - I'm sure there's a simpler form if you choose a smarter parameterization, but I can't be bothered to find it.

The Higgs vacuum is $\phi = ( 0,0,\rho)^T$. The $SU(2)$ symmetry is broken down to a subgroup that preserves this vacuum, i.e. $U\phi = \phi$. We calculate
$$
U.\phi = \rho \begin{bmatrix}
\sin (2 \theta ) \sin ^2\left(\frac{\Theta }{2}\right) \cos \varphi-\sin \theta \sin \Theta \sin \varphi  \\ \sin (2 \theta ) \sin ^2\left(\frac{\Theta }{2}\right) \sin \varphi+\sin \theta \sin \Theta \cos \varphi \\ \sin ^2\theta \cos \Theta+\cos ^2\theta
\end{bmatrix} = \rho\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This equation solves to $\theta = 0$. Then, the subgroup of $SU(2)$ that preserves the vacuum consists of matrices of the form
$$
U |_{\theta =0 } = \begin{bmatrix}
 \cos\Theta & \sin\Theta & 0 \\
 -\sin \Theta & \cos\Theta & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \in U(1) 
$$
Therefore, the symmetry breaking pattern is $SU(2) \to U(1)$.